# Windows 8.1 Surface can't connect to homegroup

Tags: windows-8.1, home-networking, homegroup

I have a Microsoft Surface Pro running Windows 8.1 and a desktop computer running Windows 8.1 on my home network. Both have their network connections set to "Private network," with file and printer sharing and network discovery turned on. I created a Homegroup on the desktop, and then tried to connect to it on the Surface.

I can get as far as entering the Homegroup password, but then, after trying for a very long time, the Surface simply fails to connect. All I get is the cryptic and unhelpful error "Something went wrong while Windows was setting up the Homegroup. Run the Homegroup troubleshooter, or try again later." Of course the Homegroup troubleshooter can't find anything wrong.

Regular file sharing between these computers works just fine, so it's not like they can't communicate with each other. There's just something going wrong with joining the Homegroup, but this error message won't tell me what it is. Does anyone know what this error means, or how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you sure neither of the machines are already part of a Homegroup?

Comment: When I go to the Homegroup Settings page on the Surface, the only option is "A Homegroup is available..." with the box to enter the Homegroup Password. Meanwhile, the same page on the desktop shows me the sliders for which items to share, the "Leave" button to leave the Homegroup, and the Homegroup password.

Comment: Also, if I go to Network and Sharing Center on the Surface, there's a "Join" link next to "Homegroup," and when I click it I see the message "Edward on Edward-Home has created a Homegroup on this network." Edward-Home is the name of my desktop, so there's only one Homegroup and I'm trying to join it.